# Sonicwall SSL-VPN + USB WiFi Adapter drops connection

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

This may need to go to server fault but wasn't sure.

**System Specs:**

```
Dell Desktop
Ralink 802.11n USB WiFi adapter 
Sonciwall NetExtender
SSL-VPN Client Windows 7 Pro x64
```

**Issue**

When attempting to transfer files greater than about 100kb (even thumb nailing a file share with images) it will drop the VPN connection.  I can remote desktop but attempting to use vSphere's web client causes it to drop out.

I have another Dell laptop with a native WiFi adapter and have transferred GIGS across the VPN with no issues.

I enabled "multimedia/gaming mode" and also disabled it to test.  No change.

Regular internet without VPN is fine.  I can download large files (1GB+) with no issues.  Speed test without VPN shows 11Mbps (50 Mbps connection) which is about average for any of my wifi devices.

**NetExtender Debug Log:**  http://pastebin.com/GrtC7Twk

**Event Viewer**

> Information   RasMan    20268
>
> CoID={9BA8BEFA-8549-4333-A786-63C4ED44A7EF}: The connection to SonicWALL NetExtender made by user  using device GENERIC12-0 was disconnected.

This is the generic error log:

```
==========NetExtender Log==========

Format: 1.0.0

Service Version: 7.5.223

Core DLL Version: 1.0.53

unknown Windows version Service Pack 1

Exported At: 04/06/2016 22:24:13


==========Log Messages==========


04/06/2016 22:21:39,    Error,  0x06000308, Engine, NetExtender has been disconnected for one of the following reasons:
-There was a break in the network connection.
-The connection was idle for longer than the configured idle timeout.
-Your user account was logged out of the SSL VPN portal.,   

04/06/2016 22:21:39,    Info,   0x00000600, Engine, Initializing engine..., 

04/06/2016 22:21:49,    Info,   0x00010600, Engine, Verifying user...,  

04/06/2016 22:21:50,    Info,   0x00030600, Engine, Initializing connection parameters...,  

04/06/2016 22:21:50,    Info,   0x00030501, Engine, Initializing connection parameters...,  

04/06/2016 22:21:50,    Info,   0x00040600, Engine, Checking updates...,    

04/06/2016 22:21:51,    Info,   0x00070600, Engine, Initializing driver..., 

04/06/2016 22:21:51,    Info,   0x00080600, Engine, Initializing security functions..., 

04/06/2016 22:21:51,    Info,   0x01000600, Engine, Connecting...,  

04/06/2016 22:21:52,    Info,   0x01010600, Engine, Connected successfully.,
```

Comment: Try to disable IPv6 on the WiFi adapter.

Comment: Nope @harrymc did not work.

Comment: Have you tried a different Wi-Fi adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in SonicWall firmware and is fixed in `SonicOS  6.2.5.1`:

```
NetExtender clients are frequently disconnected while transferring data, and one of several error messages 
displays:

• There was a break in the network connection  
• The connection was idle longer than configured idle timeout   
• Your user account was logged out of the SSLVPN Portal 

Occurs when attempting a file transfer or sending a substantial amount of traffic over 
the tunnel
```

Answer (score 0):

Ralink has been the root to a lot of evil so I suggest you get another Wifi. A normal tcp/ip connection won't unveil bad wireless hardware because it reconnect so fast - another story with vlan that needs to go though encryption negotiation. VLAN is extremely sensitive to packet drops. Increased bandwidth increase the chance for three packets in a row to be dropped and this is enough for VLAN to drop. If this is not bad enough, also Sonicwall is known for vlan dropouts, though usually fixed by firmware upgrade.